# add subtract database fields each other in my sql codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

here is my query

```
function getInventoryAvailableQty($product_id,$warehouse_id,$location_id) {

   $this->db->select_sum('quantity','addqty');
   $this->db->select_sum('total_cost','addcost');
   if($warehouse_id)
   $this->db->where('warehouse_id',$warehouse_id);
   if($location_id)
   $this->db->where('location_id',$location_id);
   if($product_id)
   $this->db->where('product_id',$product_id);
   $this->db->where('inventory_type','add');
   $query = $this->db->get($this->tablename);
   $resultAdd = $query->row();

   $this->db->select_sum('quantity','removeqty');
   $this->db->select_sum('total_cost','removecost');
   if($warehouse_id)
   $this->db->where('warehouse_id',$warehouse_id);
   if($location_id)
   $this->db->where('location_id',$location_id);
   if($product_id)
   $this->db->where('product_id',$product_id);
   $this->db->where('inventory_type','remove');
   $query1 = $this->db->get($this->tablename);
   $resultRemove = $query1->row();

   $data['imeicost'] = $resultAdd->addcost-$resultRemove->removecost;
   $data['availableQty'] = $resultAdd->addqty-$resultRemove->removeqty;
   return $data;

}
```

i want to do this in single query. because i want to add pagination on this how can i do this please suggest

Comment: Looks same as your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304254/how-to-subtract-or-add-a-field-from-another-field-in-my-sql-codeigniter

Comment: didn't get any solution so that

Comment: If it is the case for pagination please try jQuery dataTables https://www.datatables.net/

Comment: Data will be too big. it can't be managed by datatables i already tried that.

Comment: is it not possible to make a single query for this ????

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do this by using the CI Active record, but you can write the SQL Query and run it using `$this->db->query($query)`

Your query can be something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(quantity) AS addqty_add,
            SUM(total_cost) AS addcost_add
        FROM
            tbName
        WHERE
            warehouse_id = 2
        AND inventory_type = 'add'
    ) AS tb1,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(quantity) AS addqty_remove,
            SUM(total_cost) AS addcost_remove
        FROM
            tbName
        WHERE
            warehouse_id = 2
        AND inventory_type = 'remove'
    ) AS tb2
```